# jQuery Dialog Popup showing, but not popping up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a Login Control I'd like to popup.  The control is rendering, in a UI-dialog box even, but it's rendering on the page itself, not in a dialog popup.  This is my first project using jQuery UI dialogs, but I haven't had a problem in other locations.

Because my access check is all code side I have attempted to simply the issue with

```
autoOpen: true,
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
function OpenLoginDialog() {
$("#divLoginOpen").dialog({
    autoOpen: true;
    appendTo: "#divSurveyMainPage",
    modal: true,
    dialogClass: "no-close",
    width: 650,
    height: 400,
    title: "Login Please",
    show: {
        effect: "size",
        duration: 800
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 800
    },
    closeOnEscape: false
}).css('z-index', '1005');
return false;
}
```

My JSfiddle (below) has the HTML included, I've also moved the control HTML into the div where it belongs.
http://jsfiddle.net/p10bcxuq/

Please help!  Thanks!

Actual Example:  http://www.codelogically.com/Forms/Surveys/Surveys.aspx

Comment: Are you wanting the dialog to open on page load, or when they click the Take or Create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p10bcxuq/3/) - it had a lot of server side stuff which needed to be removed. You also need an opener.

```
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  OpenLoginDialog();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works nicely!  What was the issue, my appendTo?  Unfortunately StackOverflow does not allow my to upvote your comment with my low reputation, someone please give Donal some upvotes!

Comment: there were a number of issues. The first is that you need a reference to jquery and jquery.ui. The second was the server side code. Also, I think you need valid css to use the dialog. See here: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/